# Windows Process Activation Service Error 9: The storage control block address is invalid

Tags: was

I last accessed my localhost website with no issues on Monday (5/18/20), but I did a Windows update and afterwards my ISS/localhost is not connecting: both my Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) and World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC, dependent on WAS) are not running (i.e. status = 'stopped'). I checked the WAS dependencies, all of which are currently "Running".

If I go to the WAS properties from Services, I press 'Start' and receive an Error message:

```
Windows could not start the Windows Process Activation Services service on Local Computer.  
Error 9: The storage control block address is invalid.
```

Is there a way for me to change my 'storage control block address'?  I haven't found any fixes yet, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am running Windows 10 (64 bit), IIS 10.0.18362.1

Please let me know if there is extra information that would help.

**EDIT:** I also have gone to 'Turn Windows features on or off' - the box for WAS was checked, with ".NET Environment" and "Process Model" checked in the dropdown list of folders within WAS. I didn't notice any change.

Comment: I have the same issue. But haven't found a fix yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, even after receiving help from IT, **re-installing Windows 10 was the fix.**

From what I was able to gather, the problem was almost surely caused by an update.

[This article describes a windows update that has caused a lot of issues, possibly the ones here.](https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2020/05/27/microsoft-issues-windows-10-update-warning-kb4556799-free-windows-10-upgrade/#29a5414625a0)

[It also may have been the Windows 10 2004 feature update here. All of my logs stopped at the point where I ran this update.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-2004#381msgdesc)

I wish I had found a better solution. Good luck!